# php dev/testing servers

Tags: php, development-environment

I need a simple "development" server for php, e.g. not apache.

In a modern environment, such as node.js, I can run `node server.js` inside any folder, and it will run as a server running the site specified by `server.js`. I can then run another node process from a different folder, and the two servers will never interfere or get in each other's way.

Is there a similar setup for php?

With apache, it seems to me that I need to "configure" the server ahead of time; I can't just drop into some folder and serve its content on some arbitrary port.

I want a command that I can use to run a php server from inside some folder, with minimum amount of configuration, for the purpose of being a development/testing only server.

For instance, suppose this server is called `sps`, then, I should be able to:

```
cd ~/code/proj1
sps
```

Perhaps it could require a simple config file, `sps.conf` that specifies the port number the server should listen to, plus maybe information about the database connection; but nothing more.

Does such a tool exist for php?

Comment: What's wrong with apache as a web-server for development.

Comment: @zerkms I updated the question. The problem with apache (as far as I understand) I have to pre-configure it; I can't just drop in to some project and just try it.

Comment: anything should be configured to get it worked. There is no magic software that initially does what you want without any steps.

Comment: a small config file inside the project is very different from a server-specific configuration file.

Comment: each virtual host section in my config contains of 3 lines. I don't bother of creating 3 lines ;-)

Comment: It bothers me that I can't just drop into some folder and test-drive it.

Comment: @zerkms let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1683/discussion-between-hasen-j-and-zerkms)

Answer (score 5):

With the current version of PHP *(< 5.4)*, you indeed have to configure a webserver *(Apache, nginx, ...)* to serve the directory in which you'll have your website -- the directory in which you'll work.

Generally, though, you'll only have a couple of websites, which means you won't have to re-configure your webserver too often.

And if you often have to create / test some small scripts, just create an Apache VirtualHost that points to some `tests` directory, in which you'll put all your test scripts *(I have exactly that on my computer)*.

With **PHP 5.4** *(currently in alpha -- so not to be used on a production server just yet ^^)*, you'll have a [**built-in web server**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), which should pretty much answer your question.

Comment: aah, yes, that builtin server .. might be just what I want!

Answer (score 0):

try XAMPP Lite version http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html